# Boost 1.5.8 issue

Tags: c++, boost, unique-ptr

I've got lots of bugs in my old compilation machine so I decided to create a new one.

Boh project doesn't have any issue about compiling in BOOST 1.55, but in 1.5.7 or highter, only one project can compile. (Before, both are using boost 1.5.7 without problem)

Here's the bug when i'm using 1.5.8 (at char_skill.cpp)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sh8vO.png

Text mode :

```
/usr/src/blabla/Extern/include/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:193:24: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/src/blabla/Extern/include/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:558:0,
                 from /usr/src/blabla/Extern/include/boost/functional/hash.hpp:6,
                 from /usr/src/blabla/Extern/include/boost/unordered/unordered_map.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/src/blabla/Extern/include/boost/unordered_map.hpp:17,
                 from char.h:4,
                 from char_skill.cpp:7:
/usr/src/blabla/Extern/include/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:262:34: note:   'const VID' is not derived from 'const std::shared_ptr<_Tp1>'
             return hash_value(val);
                                  ^
In file included from /usr/src/blabla/Extern/include/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:558:0,
                 from /usr/src/blabla/Extern/include/boost/functional/hash.hpp:6,
                 from /usr/src/blabla/Extern/include/boost/unordered/unordered_map.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/src/blabla/Extern/include/boost/unordered_map.hpp:17,
                 from char.h:4,
                 from char_skill.cpp:7:
/usr/src/blabla/Extern/include/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:198:24: note: template<class T, class Deleter> std::size_t boost::hash_value(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&)
     inline std::size_t hash_value(std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter> const& x) {
                        ^
/usr/src/blabla/Extern/include/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:198:24: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/src/blabla/Extern/include/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:558:0,
                 from /usr/src/blabla/Extern/include/boost/functional/hash.hpp:6,
                 from /usr/src/blabla/Extern/include/boost/unordered/unordered_map.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/src/blabla/Extern/include/boost/unordered_map.hpp:17,
                 from char.h:4,
                 from char_skill.cpp:7:
/usr/src/blabla/Extern/include/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:262:34: note:   'const VID' is not derived from 'const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>'
             return hash_value(val);
                                  ^
/usr/src/blabla/Extern/include/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp: In member function 'std::size_t boost::hash<T>::operator()(const T&) const [with T = VID; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
/usr/src/blabla/Extern/include/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:263:9: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
         }
         ^
gmake: *** [OBJDIR/char_skill.o] Error 1
```

I don't know why I have this problem :x

PS : If anyone know how to install boost-all (1.5.7 or +) using freebsd ^^

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Please post a **minimal but complete example** that readers can try out (or just analyze). Include the eror mesages for the example. Also, it may be important what compiler options you're using.

Comment: I don't know if I post the char_skill.cpp or the file included

Comment: Just post a **sample** code which gives the error.